# Connecting django website to Google drive API

Tags: python, django, google-drive-api

Is it possible + legal to have a website where when people register, a personal google drive is created for them? Trying to create a website where people can upload audio files in a post, which would be displayed for other users. Can the drive be used as a hosting platform for the uploaded files? If yes, then how can this be done?

Comment: You're probably looking for an [object store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_storage), which you can connect your website to.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible + legal to have a website where when people register, a personal google drive is created for them?

You cant programmaticlly create a google account for another user.  You could request access to their google drive account and access things there but the issue will be if you want to share their files with someone else.

> Trying to create a website where people can upload audio files in a post, which would be displayed for other users.

You could use a service account to upload the files to an account that you the developer own and some how associate what was uploaded by each user.  Probably storing each users data in a directory linked to there user id in your system worked be the most logical.

The issue being here is you are going to be footing the bill for the storage space.

> Can the drive be used as a hosting platform for the uploaded files? If yes, then how can this be done?

The google drive api is really just a file storage system.  If you want the users to be able to view theses files after they will need to download them to their own machine.  Drive api wasn't really meant to host that will be viewed.